# Django app for user/account settings

Tags: django, settings, django-permissions

Im prepping for developing one project and am in process of mapping out stuff i can use for it. This project is going to need different group/user based model & object permissions and settings.

I know i can use django-objectpermissions (https://github.com/washingtontimes/django-objectpermissions) and djangos own model permissions. But there are some cases, when you dont really need to set object/model permissions, but rather a setting - can this account/user do something, which is not related to certain object or model. Has someone developed app for this? Or what kind of approach do people take when they have such need? Perhaps create dummy django model and let djangos model permissions handle the rest?

I also know, that this does something similar - https://github.com/danielroseman/django-dbsettings. But when i skimmed through the code i got impression, that those settings are all user based - i need also group based settings.

**Edit:** People keep offering me permissions apps. What i am looking for is not permissions app, but settings app. Those settings/permissions are not related to any objects.

Basically. In my project i need to answer questions - Can this user see/do this thing?. That "thing" is most likely a view. So one of the answers almost works. But the check i do at view, is not if user has permission to some model/object. Its rather, if the user has this setting turned on, of if users group has this setting turned on.

Alan

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#permissions  You can do group based permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably going to need to create your own system for this. It shouldn't be very difficult.

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(..)
    value = models.CharField(..)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

    @classmethod
    def has_setting(cls, name, user):
        user_settings = cls.objects.filter(name=name, users__in=[user]).count()
        group_settings = cls.objects.filter(name=name, groups__in=user.groups.all()).count()
        return user_settings or group_settings

    @classmethod
    def get_settings(cls, name, user, priority=User):
        user_settings = list(cls.objects.filter(name=name, users__in=[user]))
        group_settings = list(cls.objects.filter(name=name, groups__in=user.groups.all()))
        if user_settings and not group_settings: 
            return user_settings
        elif group_settings and not user_settings:
            return group_settings
        else:
            return (group_settings, user_settings)[priority==User]
```

Then you can do something like this in your views:

```
def display_frob(request):
    if Setting.has_setting('display_frob', request.user):
         settings = Setting.get_setting('display_from', request.user, priority=Group)
         values = [setting.value for setting in settings]
         # if the User was in many groups, we now have a list of values, for the setting
         # `display_frob`, that aligns with each of those groups
```

You can easy build a decorator which will do the check, and provide a list (or a single item) of values to the view.

Answer (score 0):

For permissions for "actions" (where an action is typically implemented by a view) I commonly use decorators.

The [user_passes_test](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator is great for this kind of purpose.

You could create user permissions not linked to models.

Comment: Thanks. Thats good tip. But i dont need just permissions- - i need something settings and they cannot be wholly user based - but have to be group/account based. Like - does this account or group this or that turned on. Should i create dummy model for this or that and then handle it with permissions? Or is there app for that?

Comment: I'd say do it yourself as Josh suggests

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you looking for : [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian)

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I can see that this fills the place for same stuff that this - https://github.com/washingtontimes/django-objectpermissions- does. Like i said - i need stuff, that is more settings app, than permissions. Permissions part is already covered :).